# How to arrange JSON value in angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-repeat

Hi need help on how to loop this array value into 3 column using angularjs.

Currently my view is like this
[Html table contain 3 column the value showing in vertical instead of horizontal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rs1tC.jpg)
Below is my JSON view

```js
{
  "Table1": {
  "titleList": [
      "Table1",
      "Start Date",
      "Completion Date"
    ]
    "dataList": [
      {
        "Name": "Ayu",
        "startDate": "30 Jul 2015",
        "completionDate": "30 Jul 2015"
      }
    ],
  },
  "Table2": {
  "titleList": [
      "Table2",
      "Start Date",
      "Completion Date"
    ]
    "dataList": [
      {
        "Name": "Siti",
        "startDate": "",
        "completionDate": ""
      },
      {
        "Name": "wan",
        "startDate": "",
        "completionDate": ""
      },
      {
        "Name": "nita",
        "startDate": "",
        "completionDate": ""
      },
    ],
  },
  "Table3": {
  "titleList": [
      "HGA",
      "Start Date",
      "Completion Date"
    ]
    "dataList": [
      {
        "Name": "Fatimah",
        "startDate": "",
        "completionDate": ""
      },
      {
        "Name": "Nora",
        "startDate": "",
        "completionDate": ""
      },
    ],
    
  }
}
```

My angularjs showing as below

```html
<tbody ng-repeat ="(nodeSummaryKey, nodeSummaryVal) in nodeSummary">
        
      <tr ng-if="isObject(nodeSummaryVal)" ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'" ng-repeat = "(dataKey, dataValue) in nodeSummaryVal" >
       <td ng-if="dataKey == 'titleList'" class="stx-attributes-group" 
       ng-repeat="(eachDataKey, eachDataValue) in nodeSummaryVal.titleList">{{eachDataValue}}</td>
      
       <td ng-if="dataKey == 'dataList'" ng-repeat="(eachDataKey, eachDataValue) in dataValue">
        <div ng-repeat="(eachKey, eachValue) in eachDataValue">{{eachValue}}</div> 
       
      </tr>
     </tbody>
```

Comment: I need help how to make the value showing in 1 row instead of all datalist value showing in 1 column. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your json is not correct

Comment: I have added my full JSON result.. please help if it really not correct..where is the not correct? and how to fix it? so far I can show the data from my restservice to UI just the order of it cannot show in row its shown in column instead

Answer (score 0):

You could achieve it by simple ng-repeat:

```js
angular.module('app', []).controller('Controller', function($scope) {
  $scope.table_data = {
    "Table1": {
      "titleList": ["Table1", "Start Date", "Completion Date"],
      "dataList": [{
        "Name": "Ayu",
        "startDate": "30 Jul 2015",
        "completionDate": "30 Jul 2015"
      }],
    },
    "Table2": {
      "titleList": ["Table2", "Start Date", "Completion Date"],
      "dataList": [{
        "Name": "Siti",
        "startDate": "",
        "completionDate": ""
      }, {
        "Name": "wan",
        "startDate": "",
        "completionDate": ""
      }, {
        "Name": "nita",
        "startDate": "",
        "completionDate": ""
      }, ],
    },
    "Table3": {
      "titleList": ["HGA", "Start Date", "Completion Date"],
      "dataList": [{
        "Name": "Fatimah",
        "startDate": "",
        "completionDate": ""
      }, {
        "Name": "Nora",
        "startDate": "",
        "completionDate": ""
      }, ],
    }
  };

 
});
```

```css
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
}

th, td {
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    <div ng-repeat="(dta_key,dta_value) in table_data">
      <h1>{{dta_key}}</h1>
      <table >
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th ng-repeat="thead in dta_value.titleList">{{thead}}</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr ng-repeat="tbody in dta_value.dataList">
            <td ng-repeat="trow in tbody">{{trow}}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```